# set kendo record save changes event on focus out type from the tr

Tags: gridview, kendo-ui

i am try to set save changes, update event in kendo grid.
with focus out from there row.
i am try something like this type

```
 change: function (e) {
                 if (e.field == "FirstName") {
                    dataSource.sync();
                     }
          },
```

with this its work something like this type:-
when i made any changes of my filed with name is `FirstName`.then lost focus from this field event will fire.

but i want to do this with focus out from row.
like i have three field  `FirstName,LastName,Age` now i want to change on `LastName`. and then lostfocus from there  to another filed like `Age` and change on them and then lost focus. the event will fire.
how can i do this. any idea.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Used below code for update whatever column in row.

```
 $(".k-input, .k-textbox").live("focusout", function () {
           if($(this).attr("name") == //your last field name)
           {
                    // update data
           }
        });
```

Comment: i think its update three time when i am going change on three field at a time

Comment: yes, So you want to update only last column or clicking the update button?

Comment: i am try to set every tr id="tr" and then  `change: function (e) {
                      $('#tr').blur(function () {
                               dataSource.sync();
                         });` but still not working.